# Definition field of isogeny between abelian varieties

Tags: abelian-varieties

Let $K$ be a number field. Let $A$ and $B$ be abelian varieties over $K$. Assume that $A$ and $B$ are isogenous over $\bar{K}$, the algebraic closure of $K$. We further assume that the endomorphism ring of $A_{\bar{K}}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. The question is:

Does there exist a quadratic extension $L$ over $K$ such that $A$ and $B$ are isogenous over $L$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The group of isogenies form a locally free module of rank $1$ over the endomorphism ring of $A$, hence are generated by a single isogeny of minimal degree $k$. So every isogeny is that isogeny composed with an endomorphism of $k$, so has degree $n^{2g} k$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$. Hence there are two isogenies with a given degree. The Galois action on the set of isogenies preserves degree, so the stabilizer of any isogeny is an index $2$ subgroup.

Here I'm just thinking of an isogeny as a special kind of subvariety of $A \times B$, from which it is clear that Galois invariance implies definability.

Comment: It is not generally true that ${\rm{Hom}}(A,B)$ is a projective ${\rm{End}}(A)$-module, even when ${\rm{End}}(A)$ is commutative (unclear why the first main sentence in the answer means when ${\rm{End}}(A)$ is not commutative), so this proposed argument is flawed.  To make CM counterexamples (admittedly not applicable to the context of the question), work over $\mathbf{C}$ (then descend to a number field) by using $B$ coming from the ring of integers of a CM field and $A$ coming from a proper order in that ring of integers.

Comment: If it is meant that the geometric endomorphism ring of $A$ (i.e., of $A_{\overline{K}}$) is $\mathbf{Z}$ then the answer is nonetheless affirmative via the same idea: if $f, f':A_{\overline{K}}\rightrightarrows B_{\overline{K}}$ are isogenies then they are related through composition with an element $q$ of ${\rm{End}}(A_{\overline{K}})_{\mathbf{Q}}=\mathbf{Q}$, so if $f$ and $f'$ have the same degree then $q=\pm 1$. Hence, ${\rm{Gal}}(\overline{K}/K)$ acts on such $f$ through a quadratic (or trivial) character, the kernel of which gives the desired $L$ (or $K$).

Comment: @grghxy good point.

Comment: @WillSawin, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @grghxy thank you for the comments. I meant to ask for the case when the geometric endomorphism ring is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is easy to see in terms of Galois cohomology. Let's work in the category $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ of "abelian varieties up to isogeny". Then for an object $A$ of $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathbb{Q}$, we have 
$$\operatorname{Aut}(A_{\overline{K}}) = \mathbb{Q}^\times = \left\langle - 1 \right\rangle \oplus \bigoplus_{p \textrm{ prime}} \mathbb{Z},$$
so a twist of $A$ (that is, an abelian variety that is $\overline{K}$-isogenous to  $A$) defines a class in
$$
\operatorname{H}^1(K,\operatorname{Aut}(A_{\overline{K}})) =\operatorname{H}^1(K,\left\langle - 1 \right\rangle \oplus \bigoplus_{p \textrm{ prime}} \mathbb{Z}) = \operatorname{H}^1(K,\left\langle - 1 \right\rangle) = K^{\times}/K^{\times 2},
$$
with the isomorphisms all being canonical in $K$; moreover, two twists give the same class iff they are isomorphic in $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathbb{Q}$. (Here I have used that $\operatorname{H}^1(K,\mathbb{Z})=0$ in the next-to-last step, and the Kummer sequence in the last.)

Therefore, if $B$ is as in your question, say corresponding to $t \in K^{\times}/K^{\times 2}$, then $A_L$ is isogenous  to $B_L$ iff $\sqrt{t} \in L$.

Comment: Incidentally, the same argument shows that $A$ is isogenous (over $K$) to the quadratic twist $B^t$ of $B$ (which in turn implies the desired conclusion).

Comment: This argument appears to be incorrect, or at least incomplete, because it seems very unlikely that Galois descent works in the context of isogeny categories of abelian varieties (where morphisms are not "genuine maps"), not even for elliptic curves, so such cohomological formalism would not generally apply in the manner suggested (even though it happens to give the correct answer in this case, essentially because of the argument in comments to Will Sawin's answer). To be a complete argument, such an argument should justify why Galois descent really works using maps in the isogeny category.

Comment: My argument does not need that descent is effective. I just need that the set of isomorphism classes of twists in the isogeny category injects into $\operatorname{H}^1$, which is completely formal. In the present case at least, under the assumption on the geometric endomorphism ring, descent actually *is* effective, since the $\operatorname{H}^1$ does not change when passing from the actual category of abelian varieties, where descent is of course known to hold, to the isogeny category.

Comment: I was puzzled by the assertion that such an H$^1$ "parameterizes" $K$-isogeny classes of abelian varieties that are geometrically isogenous to $A$, as surjectivity of the map to H$^1$ requires some form of effective descent.  But (as you note) you are not using that stronger assertion in the end (which still seems doubtful as a general assertion), so I withdraw my objection.

Comment: You're right that I shouldn't have written "parametrized". I have now hopefully made the text less misleading. Thanks!